# ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list when I try to remove an element from a list

Tags: python

I am making a quiz editor in Python. Inside the section of code where the user is able to remove questions from their quiz, I am given:

> ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Here is my code where the error is given:

```
# Allows the user to remove a question from the quiz
doubleCheck = ""
amountOfQuestions = 0
if choice == "3": # this is where the section of code starts where the user can remove questions
    amountOfQuestions = []
    print("\nQuestion List")
    counter = 1
    for count in range(0, len(quiz)):  # gets all the questions and prints them
        parts = quiz[count].split(",")
        amountOfQuestions = amountOfQuestions + 1 # meanwhile this tracks how many questions there are 
        print("Question ", counter, " :", parts[0])
        counter = counter + 1
    choice = input(
        str("\nChoose question number to remove (type Quit to cancel): ")) # user chooses the question they want to remove
    if int(choice) <= amountOfQuestions and int(choice) > 0:
        print("Question selected")
        doubleCheck = input(
            str("Are you sure you want to remove the quesiton? (y/n): ")) # double checks the user wants to remove the question
        if doubleCheck == "y":
            quiz.remove(choice) # when I choose "y", the error in the question on StackOverflow shows up here
            print("Question removed")
            quizEditor(quiz) # goes back to the main menu
        else:
            print("Operation Cancelled")
            quizEditor(quiz)
    elif choice == "Quit":
        print("Operation cancelled - check")
        quizEditor(quiz)
    else:
        print("invalid input")
```

The format of the list "Quiz" where all the questions are stored looks like this:

> ["The Question, The correct answer, IncorrectAnswer1,
> IncorrectAnswer2, IncorrectAnswer3,"]

One question and its answers and incorrect answers are stored inside 1 element in the list and split when they are needed by referring to its index and using the `.split()` function.

Comment: You're appending the counter values in `amountOfQuestions` where you're also checking if the choice is present. Then you're removing the choice from `quiz`. Could you explain the logic there? Why are you appending the counter values?

Comment: @vnk I append the counter values into amountOfQuestions as a form of input validation when the user chooses a question. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: If the `choice` is the index position, then you can just check if the input is lesser than the total length of the list. I don't see the point in having `amountOfQuestions` just to check if the value given by the user is present in the list.

Comment: Please refer to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) of the functions you use before asking here. `remove` removes the ***element*** you pass to it, not the index (especially not the index in string format)

Comment: @vnk I see, I will think of a better way of validating the user's input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.remove()` excepts a value to remove from the list, `choice` is a string with a number, for example `'3'`, not the actual question.

If you want to remove from the `quiz` list by index you need to convert `choice` to an `int` and use `del` or `pop` ('pop' will return the deleted value if you need it)

```
index = int(choice)
del quiz[index]
# or
quiz.pop(index)
```

Comment: Yes this works perfectly! However I will need to take 1 away from index otherwise the wrong index will be removed or it will return an "out of range" error

Answer (score 0):

The `remove()` method is used to remove a matching element from the list. Assuming that you're providing the value of `choice` to be the index to be deleted, you can use the `pop()` method.

```
quiz.pop(choice)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing within the `quiz.remove(choice)`-line is calling an operation that expects exact string matching in your case.

That means whenever `choice` is not an actual element in the list, this fails. You could catch the error in pythonic fashion via

```
try:
    quiz.remove(choice)
except ValueError:
    # do whatever
```

or make sure to check if the var is present in the list via adding it to the if-clause:

```
if choice in quiz:
     #...
```

Comment: also quiz.pop(choice, None) would catch non-existent values

Answer (score 0):

As said by Guy in the answers thread, I have to use del quiz[index], where index is entered by the user, to remove a question.

However you must take away 1 from "index" otherwise the wrong question will be removed or it will return a "out of range error"